# Expected value and indicator variable (proof check)

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, solution-verification

> In the game Risk, the attacker has three dices and the defender has two. The highest dice of the attacker is compared with the highest dice of the defender, and the second-highest dice of the attacker is compared with the second highest dice of the defender. For the attacker to win, their dice must be strictly larger than the defender. The dice of the defender are 1
> and 2
> , ordered as (1)≤(2)
> , and the dice of the attacker are 1
> , 2
> and 3
> , ordered as (1)≤(2)≤(3)

If the attackers rolls 5, 3, and 1, that would meaning $B_{(2)}=5$ and $B_{(1)} = 3$

So I want to calculate E$[I_{C_{(2)}<5}$ + $I_{C_{(1)}<2}]$ which is how many armies the attacker wins

I have found the probability function for $C_{(2)}$ which is
$$P(C_{(2)}=k)=\frac{k^2 - (k-1)^2}{36}$$
So
$$P(C_{(2)}<5)= \sum_{1}^{4} \frac{k^2 - (k-1)^2}{36} = \frac{4}{9}$$

And I have found the probability function for $C_{(1)}$ to be
$$P(C_{(1)}=k)=\frac{13-2n}{36}$$

$$P(C_{(1)}<3)= \sum_{1}^{2} \frac{13-2n}{36} = \frac{5}{9}$$

So that would mean $E[I_{C_{(2)}<5] + I_{C_{(1)}<2} = E[\frac{4}{9}+\frac{5}{9}]$ = 1

But I am not sure if this is the correct way to do it.

Comment: You have asked a large number of  nearly identical questions recently.  Can't you use the answers you received for those?

Comment: I am sorry for that, it is because my TA frequently gives wrong answers.

Comment: It is indeed correct, but you could clarify what that actually means for the defender.